# Does a SOAP Based WCF Service Operation automatically serialize with a Soap Envelope?

Tags: wcf, soap

I have a WCF Service which returns a list or array.  When it is called by a third party, does it automatically serialize into the proper soap envelope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does automatically serialize it, by wrapping it with a SOAP Envelope.

This can be disabled if required.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would I disable it?

Comment: The quickest way would be to change the binding to webHttpBinding.